# Exception not thrown in HttpRequest.GetResponse

Tags: c#

Below is C# code snippet to get Http Web response from Internet URI source. 
   It will throw exception when the client is not able to get response.
   I am curious to know whether there is any condition where no exception
   is thrown but HttpStatusCode is not OK (i.e. not is range 200-299).

Basically I need to know what are the bad status code where exception is not      thrown.

```
try{
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
catch{}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking but that will never throw an exception as you're catching it and doing nothing with it (in effect ignoring all exceptions). You're missing a closing brace after the GetReponse line too. You can see a list of status codes at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any status code in the `4xx` range is defined as a client error and will result in a `ProtocolException`. (400-Bad Request, 401-Unauthorized, etc..)
Any result in the `5xx` range is defined as a server error and will result in `CommunicationException`. (500-Internal Server Error, 502-Bad Gateway, etc..)

This is useful for example if you want to implement a retry mechanism. It would make sense to retry if the exception is a `CommunicationException` since this may be a transient error (connect failure, DNS resolution failure), but if the exception is `ProtocolException` then retrying is redundant as it should always fail.

Whether any other status code is considered an error case or not depends on the contract between the client and the server but the above are the ones defined by the HTTP standard

[List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: 3xx are redirects and are valid non-error responses (an exception won't be thrown). If `AllowAutoRedirect` is set to true then this will be transparent and your request will be forwarded to the redirect location. If it is set to false then you can decide how to handle a redirect response from the server. If in your scenario a redirect is not an expected result and is considered an error you can handle it that way, although that is usually not the case